# Want to execute a script after data is loaded in Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document-ready

I have a DIV in this data is loaded from the server.  I want my JS to execute now only when there is data in the Div.  Data is being loaded by Facebook's API

```
<Div id='profilePicsDiv' > DATA</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        var profilePicsDiv = document.getElementById('profile_pics');
        FB.api({
            method: 'friends.get'
        }, function (result) {

            // var result =resultF.data;
            // console.log(result);
            var user_ids = "";
            var totalFriends = result.length;
            // console.log(totalFriends);
            var numFriends = result ? Math.min(25, result.length) : 0;
            // console.log(numFriends);
            if (numFriends > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < numFriends; i++) {
                    var randNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (totalFriends + 1))
                    user_ids += (',' + result[randNo]);
                    randNo++;
                    if (randNo >= totalFriends) {
                        randNo = 0;
                    }
                    // console.log(user_ids);
                }
            }
            profilePicsDiv.innerHTML = user_ids;
        });
    });

}
```

Now i want after the data is loaded to execute this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var user_ids = document.getElementById('profile_pics').innerHTML;

    if (user_ids == '') {} else

    {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'See anyones secret hidden pictures :)',
            to: user_ids,
            ///  How to Fill the ID's HERE ?
        }, requestCallback);
    }
}

function requestCallback(response) {
    // Handle callback here
}

});
```

But 80% I get the Alert as Blank and 20 % time i get values , Can i do something that this function is executed after  its sure to have the data and avoide the 80% chance that its Blank?

Comment: you mean, data is loaded via AJAX after certain interval? And this happens repeatedly?

Comment: Data is being loaded by Facebook's API

Comment: Using window.onload in combination with document.ready is redundant. Get rid of window.onload and stick to jQuery. Now, how are you getting data into that div? Please post that code as well so we get the full picture. Good luck! :)

Comment: @AdiMathur - Please don't tell us you're using the Facebook API; instead, show us with the code :)

Comment: are you using this script in head tags? if yes move it to before  </body> tag and test .

Comment: I Updated the Code . one part of the code is in just below the body tag and other is just above the </body> tag

Comment: You might want to check the syntax, something seems wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook Api does ajax request to fetch results. So, this approach wont help.

Even when window is loaded completely, facebook data wont be there always ( it takes time to request ajax and get the result back from facebook server)

Also, as @jmort253 pointed,

> Using window.onload in combination with document.ready is
>   redundant.Get rid of window.onload and stick to jQuery

Do your logic on facebook api callbacks only.

**e.g.**

```
FB.api('/me/friends?fields=name,first_name,gender,picture,relationship_status,birthday', function(response) {
        // Do your logic here

    })
```

**Edit**

You should do something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    var profilePicsDiv = document.getElementById('profile_pics');
    FB.api({
        method: 'friends.get'
    }, function (result) {

        // var result =resultF.data;
        // console.log(result);
        var user_ids = "";
        var totalFriends = result.length;
        // console.log(totalFriends);
        var numFriends = result ? Math.min(25, result.length) : 0;
        // console.log(numFriends);
        if (numFriends > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < numFriends; i++) {
                var randNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (totalFriends + 1))
                user_ids += (',' + result[randNo]);
                randNo++;
                if (randNo >= totalFriends) {
                    randNo = 0;
                }
                // console.log(user_ids);
            }
        }
        profilePicsDiv.innerHTML = user_ids;
         FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'See anyones secret hidden pictures :)',
        to: user_ids,
        ///  How to Fill the ID's HERE ?
       }, requestCallback);

    });
});

});
function requestCallback(response) {
    // Handle callback here
}
```

Comment: In this case i am getting `FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). `

Comment: You havent mentioned `FB.init()` in your code. btw by following this approach you can call `FB.getLoginStatus()` on callback of `FB.init()`

Comment: Also, make sure this whole code runs after `FB js sdk` i.e. after `body` tag.